# Determine Next Item in DrupalQueue for Drupal 7

Tags: queue

I am trying to figure out how Drupal pulls what will be the next item to be processed in the queue for Drupal 7.  I have looked at `SystemQueue::claimItem` and I am missing something.  I have a queue that jams from time to time and I do not know how to figure out what record it is jamming on.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Why not add `watchdog('mymodule', 'Starting [insert id here]');` and `watchdog('mymodule', 'Completing [insert id here]');` to the start and end of the processing callback? That would let you know pretty quickly which item was started and not finished. You could even add the ids/timestamps/status to a custom database table, then add a cron job to notify you if one hasn't finished after x amount of time

Comment: It is not getting that far. My function starts like this -  `function _module_participant_upload_queue($entity_array_enqueued) {
    $start_time_queue = microtime(true);
    $nid_from_queue = $entity_array_enqueued['nid'];
    watchdog('module_participant_upload_queue', 'Starting Queue for NID ' . $nid_from_queue);`

Comment: If it's not getting that far then it's not processing any items at all and you probably need to debug further up the chain

Answer (score 0):

`SystemQueue::claimItem` has the code you're looking for. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.queue.inc/function/SystemQueue%3A%3AclaimItem/7.x

You can run the same query that will be used to get the next item in the queue. Just replace `$this->name` in the code below with the queue name.

```
    $item = db_query_range('SELECT data, item_id FROM {queue} q WHERE expire = 0 AND name = :name ORDER BY created, item_id ASC', 0, 1, array(
      ':name' => $this->name,
    ))
      ->fetchObject();
```

`$item` should have everything you're looking for.

Comment: That is what I had thought...this is where I am getting lost.  If I do  the query `select count(*) from queue where name  = 'module_participant_upload_queue';` I get 800 results.  But If I do the query above I do not get back any results.  There is the loop for managing expiration right under the code block you posted.

Comment: If you run `select data, item_id from queue where name = 'module_participant_upload_queue' LIMIT 10;` what do you get? The only reason `count(*)` should return something but the query above doesn't would be if expire isn't set to 0.

Comment: How is this going? Was this helpful?